# Automation Selenium - Dynamic XPath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

In the below XPath, the `index [1]` is changing every time. Can we handle this?

```
//button[contains(text(),'Action')][1]
```

HTML:

```
<button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle component--button btn--reset" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="icon component--icon icon-angle-down">
</span> Action</button>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code to create XPath for the particular scenario.

Comment: <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle component--button btn--reset" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon component--icon icon-angle-down"></span> Action</button>

Comment: //button[contains(text(),'Action')] - This should work. Which error are you getting? Which part is dynamic in your case? Is there the multiple buttons are available on the page with same text - Action?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one element of tag "button" and text "action" then use:

```
//button[contains(text(),'Action')]
```

If, on the other hand, the above is true AND there are multiple instances of that button, AND you want the first one, surround it first with parenthesis, then the subscript:

```
(//button[contains(text(),'Action')])[1]
```